# xss attack - more info required to patch

Tags: javascript, php, xss

Can an anybody explain how the below xss vulnerability works (what is does) and also the best way to fix (using php)

https://www.domain.com/page.php?tid=11%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=x%20onerror=alert%28document.cookie%29%3E&id=82

Comment: A URL by itself is not an XSS vulnerability.  There's nothing to fix.  Maybe the code which *uses* that query string data is vulnerable, but we can't exactly comment on code you aren't showing us.

Comment: you are most likely doing something like `echo $_GET['tid'];` on your page with out sanitizing the string.

Comment: to put it differently, what are they trying to achieve with this? It was flagged in a recent audit

Comment: Apologies for being a bit ambiguous, the get variables are sanitised but somehow not enough. My problem is that I don't understand the hack

Comment: @Jeff I've edited my answer, now it fully explains your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
You are obviously outputting raw user input ($_GET['tid'] in your case) somwhere on your page without "cleaning" it from special HTML characters.

`">` part closes some previously opened HTML tag on your page,

`<img src=x onerror=alert(document.cookie)>` inserts `img` tag with invalid source, which will cause loading error, triggering `onerror`-bound javascript.

So... if you have something like this in your php code:

```
    <a href="<?php echo $_GET['tid']?>"> some link </a>
```

It will be returned to browser like this (using $_GET['tid'] from your example ):

```
    <a href=""><img src=x onerror=alert(document.cookie)>"> some link </a>
```

So browser will:

1) Parse `a` as link with empty href

2) Try to load image and fail

3) Execute `img`'s `onerror` javascript, which will alert cookie (in an actual attack this part will not just alert cookies, but send them to attacker's server)

Suggestions:

1) Never trust/output raw user input (`htmlspecialchars()` for your `$_GET` parameters)

2) Accept/parse appropriate types only (`intval()` or `(int)` for your `$_GET` parameters)

Comment: This is not an answer but a suggestion. Please use the _comment_ feature for such things.

Comment: Feel like I wasted peoples time here so apologies - had a deeper look and found a variable that wasn't protected